# Creating New password administrator

Tags: root, passwd

I'm in the root I'm at enter new Unix password  it doesn't show and when I hit enter it says same exact thing pas

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't use a root account so perhaps you're using a different distro?

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't come with a root password. A root account exists. Also see linked https://askubuntu.com/questions/101352/why-im-not-asked-to-set-a-password-for-root-when-installing-ubuntu?rq=1

Comment: Are you perhaps asking why [Nothing shows up in the terminal when I type my password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112069/nothing-shows-up-in-the-terminal-when-i-type-my-password) ?

Comment: Please provide OS/release details